# Angular 8 PWA blank on MacOs Safari, iOS Safari & Chrome. No errors

Tags: angular, cross-browser, angular8, polyfills

My Angular 8 PWA loads perfectly on Chrome & Firefox. No errors, no compilation errors either.

However, on MacOs Safari and on iOS Safari & Chrome, the app is completely blank, no errors.

I have tried the following solutions i've found online, but no luck:

- Uncomment and install polyfills in polyfills.js
- add "crossOrigin": "use-credentials" in angular.json

Help please!

Here's ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.21
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.21
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.21
@angular/fire                     5.2.3
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@angular/pwa                      0.803.22
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.21
@schematics/angular               8.3.21
@schematics/update                0.803.21
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Here is my manifest file

```
{
  "name": "..",
  "short_name": "..",
  "gcm_sender_id": "..",
  "theme_color": "#0294a5",
  "background_color": "#0294a5",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "scope": "/",
  "description": "..",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": []
}
```

Comment: If on MacOs you open the browser devTools and access the "Application" Tab, can you see the manifest properties and Service Worker installed? Could you add your manifest file?

Comment: Hello @Francesco, 
I can see the manifest, and SW installed. Here is the manifest.webmanifest file

{
  "name": "******",
  "short_name": "********",
  "gcm_sender_id": "***********",
  "theme_color": "#0294a5",
  "background_color": "#0294a5",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "scope": "/",
  "description": "*******************.",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [..]
}

Comment: Which os versions (Mac/iOS) do you use? 
PS. If you need to add code snippets, update your question rather than adding a comment, as you can use code formatting this way and provide better readability.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
I'm on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 and iOS 13.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search for your MacOS version and PWA support, but I could not find anything.

For iOS I know that they started supporting PWAs only from version 11.3, therefore it can be a version issue. In general Apple is still far behind other competitors about PWAs.

Could you test your PWA on an iOS (version equal or later than 11.3) to see if it works? At least you could verify the version as possible cause.